# Can't get HTML code AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2

I tried to make GET HTTP response. I need to get the html code for the subsequent parsing, but responseObject is nil.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager GET:@"http://www.example.com/" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSError *error;
    HTMLParser *parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithString:responseObject error:&error];       
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Why not just use `operation.responseData`?

Comment: Initially, I did so. But I used UTF-8 and as result of convertion to NSString i got nil. Your solution is also applicable. Answer that I wrote below is better for my app architecture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For get html code we will need to build a custom response serializer to decode the NSData response from the web server into a NSString. We will need to subclass AFHTTPResponseSerializer and implement the following method:

```
- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                           data:(NSData *)data 
                          error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: but as I understood right it just return a string that between tags <body></body>?

Comment: It depends on your task.

Answer (score 2):

Why for example you have not use this solution below instead of subcalssing. It does the same thing, but you don't need to create additional files, just for overload one method.

So you can just add encoding your responseObjet in the block for example, and it will work as well. I am using POST in my example but it should work with GET in the same way but without parameters, but idea of the just conversation.

```
+ (void)makeRequestWithParams:(NSDictionary *)params
                              success:(OperationCompletionBlock)success
                              failure:(OperationCompletionBlock)failure
{
    NSString *path = @"http://www.example.com/";

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFCompoundResponseSerializer serializer];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager POST:path parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSString* encodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", encodedString);

        success(nil);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        failure(nil);
    }];
}
```